# How to set fetched value in coredata?

Tags: ios, core-data

In my case scenario is I get a value from server is custId and syncCustId.And i want to update all fields  with value of syncCustId for each custId in coredata table.So can anyone give idea or solution how to do?

Comment: are you want bach update ? i mena update a specific attribute of your table.

Comment: Yeah right. I get a custId from server and want to update some attributes based on that custId.

Comment: Keyword search "batch update core data" brings me to this article [https://www.bignerdranch.com](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/new-in-core-data-and-ios-8-batch-updating). It might help in this specific case and if developing for iOS 8 and above.